# Expose module bundled through Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am fairly new to using Webpack and I am trying to incorporate it into an existing e-commerce website. I have a simple class like so but I need to be able to access its methods within a script tag in the html. Currently I get undefined, what is the appropriate way to expose it to the entire app?

```js
//account.js
class Account {
    constructor() {
        this.transactions = [];
    }

    deposit( amount, date ) {
        this.transactions.push({ 
            amount : amount,
            date   : date
        });
    }
};

export default Account;


//app.js
import Account from './account';
const account = new Account();
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is undefined? Please post your webpack.config.js and the package.json - the error might be located there.

In general, you have to export your functions or classes you want to use elsewhere and import it there.

```
export function deposit() {..}

import {deposit as depo} from "./path-to/account"
```

Have you tried one of the following?

```
modules.export = account;

const account = require('account.js');
```

I also recommend looking into the [Webpack exports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#exports-loader) to export a global variable.